# Hacking an Ez share micro SD wifi adapter

Tags: wireless-networking, sd-card

I have one of [these micro SD card adapters](http://www.ezshare.com.cn/bgw032052/english/product.asp?Category_id=8). Right now, it allows me to transfer photos and videos using the software for the SD card. However, I am wondering if I could somehow unlock the entire card, so I could possibly use FTP or something to access files other than photos and videos.

First, I tried checking the files with the SD card in a computer, however there were no config files or anything else interesting that showed up.

Second, I saw [this post](http://haxit.blogspot.com/2013/08/hacking-transcend-wifi-sd-cards.html) which went over hacking a SanDisk wifi SD card, however after trying to access some of the directories mentioned after connecting to the card, it just redirected me to the default website (which it does if there is no file to open).

Next, I tried using a program on my computer to find any open ports, but port 80 was the only one.

Next, I tried using DirBuster to scan the file tree, which found some files that weren't of any help, and I stopped the scan after a few minutes, which it found nothing new.

I found nothing about hacking into the microSD card reader, and I couldn't find anything on the SD card itself that would suggest advanced access. Does anyone have any ideas as to what I should try next?

Comment: That hacking article is over four years old.  You would hope that every "hacker-friendly feature" that was revealed has since been fixed/removed.  Every such "feature" is also a security hole for a malicious intruder.  You probably have to look for local or physical access.  E.G. I look for three (or four) pins that could be a serial port; in this case, that means you would have to break open the adapter.

Comment: The product page for your adapter has a firmware download.  You should download it, and inspect it.  A firmware update could be one route for introducing access, i.e. installing and starting telnetd or dropbear.

Comment: @sawdust I noticed that, however it looks like the firmware is for the Wifi Smart Box, which is listed on the top left of the website. I don't think it has anything to do with the wifi SD card adapter.